# how to pre-fix a piece of text in github "git log" using shell-script

Tags: regex, git, bash, shell, git-log

I need to make a github commit (the text), from the git command `git log` into a link in an email. So the recipient can click on the link and go directly to the change.

I receive a long list containing lines with the text:

`commit some_long_string_of_hexadecimals`

and I need to transform this into:

`commit https://github.com/account/repo/commit/some_long_string_of_hexadecimals`

The log I am receiving contain n-amount of these logs, so I need the script to do this for all instances of this (some_long_string_of_hexadecimals).

Here are a few example log statements:

```
commit a98a897a67896a987698a769786a987a6987697a6
Author: Some Person <some@email.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 29 09:48:52 2016 +0200

    long message describing change.

commit a98a897a67896a987698a769786a987a6987697a6
Author: Some Person <some@email.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 29 09:48:52 2016 +0200

    more description
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
commit https://github.com/account/repo/commit/a98a897a67896a987698a769786a987a6987697a6
Author: Some Person <some@email.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 29 09:48:52 2016 +0200

    added handling of running tests from within a docker container
```

How do I achieve this using a shell command ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be good to see a concrete example of what you have and what you need to convert it into.

Comment: it is really just echo $(git log) >> logfile.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '$1 == "commit" {$2 = "https://github.com/account/repo/commit/" $2} 1'
```

1. check if field 1 equals "commit"
2. if so, prepend to field 2
3. if line matched, print modified line, else print line as is